# how to remove unused external libraries Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, libraries

I am working on a project with Intellij and for some reason we imported too many libraries. now I need to remove all the unnecessary libraries. is there a way to remove them without removing the actually used libraries?

Comment: Are you using something like Maven or Gradle to manage this?

Comment: I am using maven

Comment: Delete the dependencies which you don't believe are necessary until your application doesn't compile?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which is necessary and which is not. I was looking for a way to let me know that. and also the problem is not with the dependencies, the problem is with the external jars I guess

Comment: Why do you have external JARs loaded into your project if you're relying on Maven to resolve your dependencies?

Comment: some jars wasn't resolved as maven dependencies so i had to add them manually.

Comment: @A.khaled https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7222-jonnyzzz-dependencies